# Capturing image from an Android Face Tracker application

Tags: android, android-camera, face

I'm creating a snapchat style app using Android's Sample Face Tracker code. I have a system set up to take a screenshot of the whole view in order to take a picture. It is successfully taking a screenshot, creating an image and saving it in an android folder. However, it's showing the camera portion as black. The picture contains the UI as well as the Graphical Overlay but not the camera. The code that I'm using to capture the screenshot as a bitmap is below.

Face Tracker Code: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker

```
    View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```